# Serenity get client ID

Tags: rust, discord, bots

How do you get the id of the client in the EventHandler when using Serenity for a discord bot?

I am unsure of how to get the client and its id. I need this so that I can make sure that the message that the bot is responding to isn't its own. Also, no, checking if the message was sent by a bot won't work because I need to make it so that it can respond to the messages of other bots too. If there is another way without getting the id of the client in the EventHandler, I would be fine with that too. Static variables do not count.

Comment: Would this not be [`Message.author`](https://docs.rs/serenity/latest/serenity/model/channel/struct.Message.html#structfield.author)?

Comment: No, I need the client's id, aka the bot's id, not the id of the person who sent the message.

Comment: Ah, then in that case you can capture the ID and store it on your struct that implements `EventHandler`, or store it in client data and look it up through the context.

Comment: Note, however, that not responding to bots at all is the right approach. You don't want your bot talking to other bots -- that's how you get into message loops.

Comment: I actually want my bot to be able to respond to other bots.

Comment: Also how would I implement that cdhowie?

Comment: It turns out you don't need to capture the ID.  I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the arguments you are given is a [`Context`](https://docs.rs/serenity/latest/serenity/client/struct.Context.html) value, and you can get the current user through its cache, from [`Cache::current_user_id()`](https://docs.rs/serenity/latest/serenity/cache/struct.Cache.html#method.current_user_id):

```
// Assuming ctx is the name of the Context argument:
let my_uid = ctx.cache.current_user_id();
```

This requires the `cache` feature of the `serenity` crate.

Answer (score 0):

There's an even better option for this exact case:

```
if msg.is_own(&ctx.cache) {
    println!("is own! {}",msg.content);
    return;
}
```

This also requires the `cache` feature of the `serenity` crate.